# How can I delegate the LaunchRequest to an IntentRequest using the alexa-sdk from npm

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill in node using the [alexa-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alexa-sdk). I am using a [dialog model](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html) to handle the user interaction. I am having some trouble passing the flow along to new [request types](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html), such as from the launch request to an intent request.

Below is an example of my handlers and what I want ideally. My specific usecase is that I would like to ask some questions of the user and then send them to different intents based on what they answer. In the intents I would like to have access to the request objects, as if they entered that intent originally, so the dialog model can do its work.

```
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
        this.emit('Entry'); // this does not do what I want
    },
    'Entry': function () {
        let request = this.event.request; // this is the launch request object.
        // I would like to get the request object for Entry, like if the user started here

        // ask some questions, potentially passing the torch to a new intent based on the answers
    }
};
```

So, is there any way to "call" an intent like the user originally made a request to that intent? Sorry if I missed something obvious in the documentation, I searched around pretty thoroughly I think, but there is A LOT of documentation. ps: I could manually construct the request object of course, but I really should not have to I feel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no way yet to call on an intent as you are asking.

If you go through the syntax description of dialog directieves [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#syntax), it says:

> Note that you cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive, so the intent name and set of slots must match the intent sent to your skill.

With returning a dialog directive you are able to 'elicit' or 'confirm' slots or intents, or even let a delegate handle your dialog for you, with prompts and reprompts set in the Skill Builder.

As far as i know, the only solution to trigger a specific intent is to make the user invoke it. You can guide the user into saying a specific utternace to trigger your intent.

As for saving older requests, you can use [session attributes](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-parameters). Just build a response after your Launch with a session attribute containing the whole LaunchRequest.

```
"sessionAttributes": {
"oldRequest": this.event.request
}
```

Comment: Okay, I am going to restructure the dialog of my app a bit then, so the launch request request the user to call an intent. Thank you for your time :)